# Derivative of Norm ($K$ means)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Sorry if I've missed this somewhere else but I'm struggling. I'm attempting to follow the optimization routine of $K$-means. I completely understand the intuition, but am shaky on how the opimizaion is being computed.

Given $$J =\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{k=1}^{K}{r_{nk}||x_n-\mu_k||^2}.$$ We can compute the optimal $\mu_k$ by taking the derivative and setting to $0$. So why does that turn out to be

$$0 =2\sum_{n=1}^{N}{r_{nk}(x_n-\mu_k)}$$ instead of
$$0 =(-1)2\sum_{n=1}^{N}{r_{nk}(x_n-\mu_k)}$$ ($-1$ is from the inner portion of the chain rule)?

I'm thinking this has something to do with the norm, but perhaps I'm wrong. Thank you for the help.